# Android Map OnClick Tracker

Tags: android, google-maps, onclick, gps

Ok so I have a simple map that follows your location as you move.

I am trying to get it so that it only does this if a toggle button is clicked.

In the long run I am looking to make an app that tracks journeys and stores them in a database. so when I press start I will be drawing my current location to my new current location and then when I press stop it saves the journey.

However when I add a onClick listener my app is just crashing on start up. Any ideas?

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    }

    if(mMap != null) {
        //Enable GPS
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        Location previousLocation = mMap.getMyLocation();
        final LatLng previousPos = new LatLng(previousLocation.getLatitude(), previousLocation.getLongitude());

        final ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.startStop);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(button.isChecked()) {

                    //Set the map to current location
                    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

                        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                            LatLng position = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());


                            //Zoom parameter is set to 17
                            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 17);


                            //Use map.animateCamera(update) if you want moving effect
                            mMap.moveCamera(update);

                        }

                    });

                }
                else {

                }

            }
        });



    }

}
 }
```

Here is the logcat error

```
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  Unable to start activity                                                                                         ComponentInfo{com.example.hellomap/com.example.hellomap.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
   11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237) 
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275):  at com.example.hellomap.MainActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(MainActivity.java:50)
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275):  at com.example.hellomap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
  11-09 19:06:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(12275):  at          android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
```

Comment: Add your log with exception.

Comment: Is what I have added to the question what you wanted to see?

Comment: So what is the line number 50 in your `MainActivity`? I think this `final LatLng previousPos = new LatLng(previousLocation.getLatitude(), previousLocation.getLongitude());`

Comment: Correct. It also says that value previousPos is not used.

Comment: Start function is working now but when I set the button to stop it doesnt stop

Comment: The map was not able to get location, so the returned location was null and app has been crashed.

Comment: Nevermind sorted it now :)

Comment: So is your stop button code working now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took out the two lines of code 49 and 50. It now works! :)

```
  //    Location previousLocation = mMap.getMyLocation();
        //final LatLng previousPos = new LatLng(previousLocation.getLatitude(), previousLocation.getLongitude());
```